# Duplicate entry for key [ERROR:1062, SQLSTATE:23000] - but key doesn't exist in table

Tags: mysql

I get the error:

```
Duplicate entry '978e9917-4191-472a-a6dc-729a92aed887' for key 'Component.FKvzrqjhn2bz1iobdd2ztu0eyc' [ERROR:1062, SQLSTATE:23000]
```

My table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE `Component` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uuid` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `study_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_hv7ffe3qq68l092inojua2sxa` (`study_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_hv7ffe3qq68l092inojua2sxa` FOREIGN KEY (`study_id`) REFERENCES `Study` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10399 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

And I use:

```
ALTER TABLE `Component` ADD UNIQUE KEY `FKvzrqjhn2bz1iobdd2ztu0eyc` (`uuid`);
```

I add indexes to other tables using the same command (with different key names) and it works without problems - it fails only in this table. I tried different names with no success. Does anyone know why? I'm using MySQL version 8.0.31-0ubuntu0.22.04.1.

Comment: The error message tells that your data contains duplicated rows. You must remove excess duplicates from your table firstly. Look at `SELECT uuid FROM Component GROUP BY 1 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;` - it will show all duplicated `uuid` values.

Comment: You are so right! Thank you @Akina!